# Create new dataframe combining two different dataframe columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframe

df1# - This has userid and the products bought by the corresponding user.

```
Userid, Productid,    Ordered_Qty
user1           1         1
user1           2         1
user1           3         1
user2           4         1
user2           5         1
user2           3         1
user3           2         1
user3           4         1
user3           5         1
```

df2# - This has product master

```
Productid, some_attribute
1             "xsff"
2             "xsff"                
3             "xsff"
4             "xsff" 
5             "xsff"
```

Now, I would like to create new dataframe that looks like below,

```
Row - Userid from df1
columns - Productid from df2
```

New dataframe# - [i,j] value corresponds to the df1# Ordered_Qty(any qty).Basically I wanted to have all the values from df2 - Productid but fill the values in new dataframe
from the df1. if df1 doesn't have entry for userid(row) & product(col) combination then, I like to keep zero in it

```
      1 2 3 4 5
user1 1 1 1 0 0
user2 0 0 1 1 1 
user3 0 1 0 1 1
```

To achieve this, What I did is

```
new_dataframe = pd.dataframe(0,index=df1.Userid.unique(),columns=df2.Productid.unique())

for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    userid = row['Userid']
    productid = row['Productid']
    ord_qty =  row['Ordered_Qty']
    new_dataframe.loc[userid][productid] = ord_qty
```

However this way of doing taking more time and eventually resulting in memory error.
Is there better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pivot` or `pivot_table` or `crosstab`:

```
df3 = df.pivot(index='Userid', columns='Productid').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
df3.columns = df3.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

Or:

```
df3 = df.pivot_table(index='Userid', columns='Productid', fill_value=0)
df3.columns = df3.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

Or:

```
df3 = pd.crosstab(df['Userid'], df['Productid'])
```

And then:

```
df3 = df3.reindex(columns=df2.Productid.unique(), fill_value=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use Crosstab:

```
pandas.crosstab(df['userid'], df['productid'])
```